# Android WebView HTML with cookies

Tags: android, html, cookies, webview

I am trying to pull HTML data out of a `WebView`.  I've seen this done a thousand times and I've even gotten it to work myself.  However, my new project leads to an interesting situation: I need to login to a site through a `WebView` and *then* pull the HTML.  Obviously, the `Socket` method doesn't work, because in order for a webpage to be returned you need the cookie for authentication.  I've also tried the `JavascriptInterface` trick, but that didn't work either.  I'm thinking the best way to achieve this is to use `HttpGet` with `CookieManager`?  Does anyone know how I can get raw HTML code from a `WebView` with an auth cookie?  Thanks!

EDIT: I did some JS injection and didn't see any cookies... so it might not be a cookie issue?  But the links that you get redirected to are generic, like `mainPage?a=1` and `infoPage`.  You cannot simply copy/paste the links into another browser you *have* to be logged in to view these links.  For those of you who are web experts, you may know an easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebView` isn't really meant for getting HTML for programmatic use, the idea is that it's just a direct window to a URL for user interaction.

To get what you want, you can use a `java.net.HttpURLConnection` with a `CookieManager`, it's worked fine for me on Android and it's suggested in the Android SDK docs:

```
// in an activity's onCreate:
cookieManager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);

// later on
void getAPage(URL url) {
   HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

   System.out.println("hello from huc, response code is: " + huc.getResponseCode());

   // huc.getInputStream() gives you the content.
}
```

The `CookieManager` will persist all cookies through the lifetime of the application without you having to do anything extra. You can make posts with `HttpURLConnection` too.

Comment: `CookieHandler.setDefault()` takes in a `CookieHandler` as an argument, not a `CookieManager`, so I'm not sure this approach works as it is.